# Как найти место, где бросается исключение в С++?

Tags: c++, debian, исключения, gcc

Падает приложение с эксепшеном, в бактрейсе (gdb) - системные вызовы. Есть какие-нибудь варианты найти место, где бросается исключение?

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  Invalid argument

gcc 4.8, debian

Дамп: http://pastebin.com/ffX5mJqz

Comment: "есть какие нибудь варианты найти место где бросает?" да - посмотреть бактрейс.

Comment: добавил в начало

Comment: @orion_gm какая у Вас IDE? Вы из нее берете багтрейс?

Comment: бактрейс идет из gdb

Comment: @orion_gm посмотрите в IDE. При том же багтрейсе получите гораздо больше информации.

Comment: @orion_gm не знаю, как на русском SO, на обычном выкладывание ссылок в вопросе на сторонние ресурсы не приветсвуется. Для этого есть причины, например я не могу прочитать ваш коредамп.

Comment: @Slava, в вопрос же не влезет? Там 59034 символа, а лимит на размер вопроса - 30000.

Comment: @Qwertiy так весь бактрейс и не нужен, достаточно последник 5-10 вызовов.

Comment: @Slava, почему бы тебе не внести их в виде правки?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что сайт pastebin для меня недоступен.

Comment: @Slava, нормальный же сайт, за что его так?

Comment: @Qwertiy работаю в банке, коммуникации обрезаны, для избежания инсайдинга.

Comment: @Slava, backtrace ничем в случае с исключением не поможет — поднимаясь «вверх» исключение разматывает стек и когда исключение отлавливается ничего не известно о его происхождении — стека больше нет.

Comment: @tutankhamun тогда уж `бэктрейс`, а лучше было бы на английском.

Answer (score 4):

Просто напишите `catch throw` в gdb до запуска программы. После этого gdb будет останавливаться при каждом броске исключения в месте его возникновения.

**UPD**: по поводу перехватывания исключений определенного типа. На моей платформе gdb при вызове `catch throw` просто ставит breakpoint на функцию `__cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw`. Это внутренняя функция, которая вызывается при броске исключения. Если присмотреться, в нее помимо прочего передается `typeinfo` о типе брошенного исключения. Поэтому можно просто поставить условие на breakpoint по значению этого параметра.

Пример того, как получить стектрейс для исключения с типом `std::invalid_argument`:

```
$ cat test.cc
#include <stdexcept>

void foo() {
  throw std::invalid_argument("other_invalid_argument");
}

int main() {
  try {
    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid_argument");
  } catch (...) { }
  try {
    throw std::range_error("range_error");
  } catch (...) { }
  foo();
}

$ g++ -g -O0 ./test.cc
$ ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  other_invalid_argument
Aborted (core dumped)

$ gdb --args ./a.out
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 1 (throw)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
Loading gdb's copy of v17 libstdc++ pretty-printers.
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020d0 <typeinfo for std::invalid_argument@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400ab0 <std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
62  ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) set $info=tinfo             <-- запоминаем tinfo
(gdb) cond 1 tinfo==$info         <-- ставим условие на catchpoint
(gdb) c    
Continuing.
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020d0 <typeinfo for std::invalid_argument@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400ab0 <std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
62  in ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc
(gdb) bt  <-- интересующий нас стектрейс
#0  __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020d0 <typeinfo for std::invalid_argument@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400ab0 <std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
#1  0x0000000000400c5f in foo () at ./test.cc:4
#2  0x0000000000400de9 in main () at ./test.cc:14
```

**UPD2**: придумал еще способ, правда он не работает для многопоточных програм. Можно создавать checkpoint при каждом броске исключения, а после того, как программа упадет, восстанавливаться с последнего checkpoint-а. Программа та же, что и выше:

```
$ gdb --args ./a.out
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 1 (throw)
(gdb) commands 1
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>checkpoint 
>c
>end
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
Loading gdb's copy of v17 libstdc++ pretty-printers.
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020d0 <typeinfo for std::invalid_argument@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400ab0 <std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
62  ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc: No such file or directory.
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020b0 <typeinfo for std::range_error@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400a10 <std::range_error::~range_error()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
62  in ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020d0 <typeinfo for std::invalid_argument@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400ab0 <std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
62  in ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  other_invalid_argument

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7531cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info checkpoints
  3 process 20315 at 0x7ffff7b348b0, file ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc, line 62
  2 process 20314 at 0x7ffff7b348b0, file ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc, line 62
  1 process 20313 at 0x7ffff7b348b0, file ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc, line 62
* 0 process 20309 (main process) at 0x7ffff7531cc9, file ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c, line 56
(gdb) restart 3
Switching to process 20315
#0  __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020d0 <typeinfo for std::invalid_argument@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400ab0 <std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
62  ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x603090, 
    tinfo=0x6020d0 <typeinfo for std::invalid_argument@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, 
    dest=0x400ab0 <std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@plt>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
#1  0x0000000000400c5f in foo () at ./test.cc:4
#2  0x0000000000400de9 in main () at ./test.cc:14
```

Comment: Спасибо, по типу исключения как-то можно сделать, например только invald_argument?

Comment: Судя по тому, что в багтрейсе, никаким исключением не выловится.

Comment: какие есть варианты? Последнее в консоле это
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what(): Invalid argument

 и киляется процесс

Comment: @orion_gm, "по типу исключения как-то можно сделать" -- не знаю если честно, вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835728/gdb-how-to-break-when-a-specific-exception-type-is-thrown обсуждается этот вопрос, но нормального ответа нет, только непереносимые хаки. А у вас много исключений в программе кидается? Можно пропустить несколько неинтересных до тех пор пока не встретится нужное необработанное.

Comment: Не так много, но проект большой и отыскать их проблемно

Comment: @orion_gm, обновил ответ

Comment: Только вот у ТС exception не в main thread, и ситуация больше напоминает [вот это](http://gcc-help.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/mGegtPXh/no-useful-backtrace-after-uncaught-exception-in-std-thread) ([дальнейший разбор полетов](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55917))

Comment: @orion_gm, если не окажется возможности смоделировать ситуацию в gdb, то придется перехватывать std::system_error исключения в try ... catch во всех корневых функциях потоков и видимо [как-то так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665829/how-can-i-print-stack-trace-for-caught-exceptions-in-c-code-injection-in-c) печатать trace

Comment: @avp, по ссылке проблема была из-за бага в gcc и того, что thread функция была noexcept. Мне кажется способ из **UPD** должен работать.

Comment: Вы про дебаггер? Если он сможет поймать в нем эту ситуацию (я по обсуждению понял, что валится уже продакшн). Кстати, здесь функция тоже noexcept

Comment: @avp, ну не знаю, пока все что я вижу в логах ТС, это вызовы std::terminate, которые являются результатами необработанных исключений.

Comment: В том-то и дело. Библиотека бросает std::system_error и его никто не ловит, стек раскручивается до pthread_create и runtime вызывает terminate для потока. Надо ловить. (или переписать без исключений).

Answer (score 1):

Если приложение падает в результате исключения, то можно его отловить посредством ***try-catch***.

Если же приложение падает, например, из-за сегфолта, то тогда только ищите ошибку посредством багтрейсинга. Хотя можно и корректно пытаться выйти используя сигналы.

Comment: Спасибо. Это в случае когда известно что его бросает, а сейчас это не известно

Comment: "Хотя можно и корректно пытаться выйти используя сигналы." лучше не стоит, практически всегда это приводит к большим проблемам, чем пытаетесь избежать.

Comment: @orion_gm Если умеете пользоваться try-catch, то, во-первых, Вы сможете узнать чем именно вызвано исключение (например, делением на ноль), а во-вторых, последовательно "сжимая" область try сможете "выйти" на место ошибки.

Comment: @Slava Читаем правильно... Можно пытаться. И в большинстве случаем, это удастся. Ни к каким проблемам не приведет. Программу **нужно** в случае падения завершить корректно, а не продолжать ее потуги что-либо выполнить. А обработка сигнала по сути единственный способ корректно ее завершить.

Comment: @MaxZS "Ни к каким проблемам не приведет. Программу нужно в случае падения завершить корректно, а не продолжать ее потуги что-либо выполнить"  приведет, проверено на практике неоднократно. Вкратце - лучше пусть падает с коредампом, чем потом читать логи и гадать, что же там сломалось и почему.

Comment: @Slava Читать дампы нужно на этапе разработки и отладки. А когда программа уже в релизе и находится у пользователей, то кто ее дампы будет читать? Думаете, что Вы сможете заставить пользователя читать дамп (или выслать дамп Вам на мыло)? Или думаете, что падая программа вышлет Вам дамп? Или Вы хотите на экран вывалить пользователю дамп и алерты? Глупости. Программа должна красиво выйти (возможно, с красивым варнингом и просьбой).

Comment: @MaxZS зависит от того, разрабатываете вы гуи приложения, или серверные. Да я читаю дампы в продакшене, и попытки спрятать ошибку и "красиво завершиться" приводят к тому, что время на исправление ошибки увеличивается на порядки. Но и с клиенсткими приложениями совершенно не обязательно пользователся заставлять его читать, они могут переслать коредамп вам.

Comment: @Slava про пересылку дампа я уже Вам написал. Это просто смешно. Возможно, только если у Вас одна клиентская копия и один заказчик с которым Вы общаетесь.